# What is the passive form of the following?

Tags: passive-voice

They had someone to help them. Is it "they had been helped"?

Answer (score 1):

As you know the verb "have" in the sense of *possess*, is a non acting verb. So, it is not ordinarily employed in the passive voice. But the second verb(help) could be used in the passive voice.Consequently the passive form of the sentence you've mentioned is:

> They were helped by someone.